# Book series with alien ghosts vulnerable to radio

Tags: story-identification, first-contact

I read a sci-fi series in the 90's which I remember many details but I can not recall the author or any titles in the series.

What I can remember is:

- There is a first-contact situation where the humans broadcast a prepared welcome message over radio, following which the alien immediately open fire.
- It is later discovered that some members of the species are vulnerable to radiowaves
- These aliens have "died", in that their corporeal bodies are dead but the live on as a sort of ghost
- If parts of a dead alien is severed and brought elsewhere they can travel instantly between the parts, giving their society FTL communication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timothy Zahn's *[Conquerors'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquerors%27)* trilogy.

> It is herein revealed that the Zhirrzh preserve the psyches of their dead as holographic 'Elders', and that the injury done to these by radio transmission, has provoked most of their interstellar wars.

From [the answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214675/story-about-a-space-war-and-a-human-prisoner-of-war-captured-by-alien-enemy?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> The Zhirrzh have a special organ (the fsss) that is extracted at death, and from which the animus of the departed Zhirrzh (the "elder") is able to manifest and communicate with the living. It is possible to divide this organ in two, so that the elder can manifest in either of 2 places. By placing groups of dozens to a few hundred of these in places, they can create a faster-than-light communication system where messages are routed among the elders. It is also how early-warning systems are constructed, such as the one found by the human ground forces.

Found with a search for `science fiction aliens killed by radio`, which led me to [this page](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/580366/).